# EF Core - fetch values from two different tables and merge them to one query

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Here I am using `.net` and `ef-core`. I have two tables where one is `Newsfeed` and other one is `Promotion`. I have created a function to fetch records from `Newsfeed` table. But however I want to include a promotion (if available) only after every 3 records of Newsfeeds. Can any one suggest me a solution for this.

```
var entityList = await _context.Set<NewsFeed>().ToListAsync();
return Mapper.Map<ICollection<NewsFeedDto>>(entityList);

//models
public class NewsFeedDto {
    public long NewsFeedId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string Title{ get; set; }
}

public class PromotionDto {
    public long PromotionId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public decimal Value{ get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }  
}
```

The records should be as follow

- NewsFeed1
- NewsFeed2
- NewsFeed3
- Promotion1
- NewsFeed4
- NewsFeed5
- NewsFeed6
- Promotion2
  .....

Comment: Add Promotions query and final DTO for both recordsets.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv But I want to include a promotion record after every 10 records of newsfeeds

Comment: I can create any query via LINQ or mix it with client-side post-processing, but without models and result DTO, I have no information to do that.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Thank you, I have updated the answer

Comment: CreateOn and Title are present on two models, so you need promotions info? What is Id in DTO?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I want to have a arraylist where it includes newsfeeds and promotions records (Which means OutPutDto). Id in OutPutDto is using either for newsfeedId or promotionId.  I want to include a promotion (if available) only after every 10 records of Newsfeeds. Which means if there is 10 newsfeed records then 11th one should be a promotion one, and so on.

Comment: Any limitations by date, count, pagination? I think you don't want to grab whole history.

Comment: would better if can add pagination

Comment: Sorry, for delay, no time. How Promotion`s CreatedOn is correlated with NewsFeed's CreatedOn? What to do if there are few promotions on the same date?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I just want to do something like in facebook. In facebook when you are scrolling you can see newsfeed and also advertisments in between newsfeeds. So thats what I want to do in here

Comment: So, one promotion per 10 newsfeed record. Thinking how to avoid promotion duplicates.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv yes